# Contact Term and Schwinger Term

Tags: quantum-field-theory, correlation-functions

In field theory, when 4-divergences of time-ordered Green's functions are computed, there are extra terms known as 'Schwinger terms'.

When deriving the quantum equations of motion for time-ordered Green's functions, there are extra terms known as 'Contact terms'.

Are **contact terms** and **Schwinger terms** one and the same?  Or is one a special case of the other? Or are they completely unrelated things?  [There's also some kind of relationship with $\mathcal{L}_\text{int}\neq\mathcal{H}_\text{int}$, when I can't place my finger on.]

Comment: Suggestion to the question (v1): While you are at it, you could also ask about 'Seagull terms'.

Answer (score 11):

They are different.

'Schwinger terms' arise as central or abelian (or even non-abelian) extensions of current algebras of operators, very often as a consequence of the regularization procedure. They are source of anomalies. The original paper is short and readable: *Field theory and commutators* by J. Schwinger. You can read more in Moshe's answer to my question [Classical and quantum anomalies](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/33195/classical-and-quantum-anomalies) and references therein.

On the other hand, 'contact terms' are terms that show up when different fields are evaluated at the same point. They are present in the Schwinger-Dyson equations and in Ward identities, for example. See [Schwinger-Dyson equation on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwinger%E2%80%93Dyson_equation) and Maimon's answer (or mine) to this question [On-shell symmetry from a path integral point of view](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/26888/on-shell-symmetry-from-a-path-integral-point-of-view/30045#comment141113_30045).

Comment: I have a question that wthether the contact terms can be negnect in general, or under what circumstances we can negnect the contact terms?